# Google Drive SDK login with email address and password

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I was able to upload a picture to my Google Drive with this [example](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android) based on the Google Drive SDK. My problem now is that the user has to select an account on the phone at the beginning. I want to give my users the option to login with an other account as they have on the phone. So I want that my user can login with a gmail address and the password. Is that possible or do I have to go over the account chooser?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `AccountPicker` to pick an account and then initialize the authorization on the behalf of that account. Our Android tutorial already covers what you're willing to achieve on https://developers.google.com/drive/auth/android#select_the_account_to_authorize_with